# What's wrong with Android-Studio imports

Tags: java, android, android-studio, constants

Apparently Google no longer supports the Eclipse Android IDE, and I've been having some odd problems with imports in Android studio. When I pasted a code snipped with `ContextMenu menu`, it wouldn't import it, even with alt+enter it would not show the appropriate `android.view.ContextMenu`.

Now I pasted an example with `LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE`, and unfortunately it won't recognize it at all - alt+enter suggests creating a constant, class, field, or renaming. I don't remember having this problem in Eclipse.

Where do I find these constants, or more importantly, how do I get Android-studio to get the right imports without memorizing where these classes/constants are?

Comment: Did you move from an `ant` to `gradle` build properly?

Comment: I don't think this particular project was ever an ant project.

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with Android-Studio imports?

Not much, I'm using it (resp. Intellij Idea) for years now.

> When I pasted a code snipped with ContextMenu menu, it wouldn't import
>   it, even with alt+enter it would not show the appropriate
>   android.view.ContextMenu.

This definitely works for me, so it's certainly not a missing feature. I would suspect something in your project / module setup being funny. If you're really serious about it I would try to reproduce the issue on a vanilla project.

> Now I pasted an example with LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE, and
>   unfortunately it won't recognize it at all - alt+enter suggests
>   creating a constant, class, field, or renaming.

I can confirm that one. Annoys me too. But then: How should the IDE know about a single String matching some constant definition? I would be surprised if Eclipse did any better...

Try "Symbol-Search" (Ctrl Alt Shift N) or "Search everywhere" (Shift Shift), this should mitigate the problem.